# Sinusoid with period as a linear function of time

Tags: functions, signal-processing, periodic-functions, almost-periodic-functions, quasiperiodic-function

I have tried many different methods but to no avail. I am trying to construct a sinusoidal function (e.g. sin(2πf*(x-a))) with a linearly changing period. This is my thought process:

*P(t) = a + bt*

*f(t) = 1/P(t)*

We can use the frequency to construct a sinusoid:

*y = sin(2π f(t) (t-a))*

However, the resulting function does not seem to have a linearly increasing period. Admittedly, my method for checking this could be flawed as I used values from Desmos to check several dP/dt. I have also tried using the integral of 2pi*f inside my sine function, but with the same result. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

So you are constructing functions in the form

$$f(t) = \sin \left(2\pi\cdot\frac{t-a}{a+bt}\right)$$

But when $t\to \infty$, the fraction has a limit $1/b$, so $f$ no longer crosses zero for large enough $t$ but converges to a constant.

When limited in small $t$ though it may work, for example $\sin(2\pi (t-1)/(1+.1t))$  in WolframAlpha:

- [for $t\le 10$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+sin%282pi*%28t-1%29%2F%281%2B.1t%29%29+from+t%3D-10+to+10), which still oscillates,
- [for $t\le 1000$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+sin%282pi*%28t-1%29%2F%281%2B.1t%29%29+from+t%3D-10+to+1000), which is more apparent that $f$ no longer crosses zero for large enough $t$.

Comment: this makes sense, but is there a way to check that the period is indeed a linear function of time as intended? In other words, a solution for the time derivative of the period.